# MongoDB Insert performance - Huge table with a couple of Indexes

Tags: mongodb

I am testing Mongo DB to be used in a database with a huge table of about 30 billion records of about 200 bytes each. I understand that Sharding is needed for that kind of volume, so I am trying to get 1 to 2 billion records on one machine. I have reached 1 billion records on a machine with 2 CPU's / 6 cores each, and 64 GB of RAM. I mongoimport-ed without indexes, and speed was okay (average 14k records/s). I added indexes, which took a very long time, but that is okay as it is a one time thing. Now inserting new records into the database is taking a very long time. As far as I can tell, the machine is not loaded while inserting records (CPU, RAM, and I/O are in good shape). How is it possible to speed -up inserting new records?

Comment: Can you tell us what the insert speed is now? Perhaps in average milliseconds per insert.

Comment: The insert speed now, with 1 billion records in the table and 2 indexes defined, is about 200 records per second.

Comment: what kind of index are the 2 index ? _id or sparse or unique or normal?

Comment: And are you using bulk insert when you inserting data? As far as I know, bulk insert will perform betten than insert one record every time.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend adding this host to MMS (http://mms.10gen.com/help/overview.html#installation) - make sure you install with munin-node support and that will give you the most information.  This will allow you to track what might be slowing you down.  Sorry I can't be more specific in the answer, but there are many, many possible explanations here.  Some general points:

- Adding indexes means that that the indexes as well as your working data set will be in RAM now, this may have strained your resources (look for page faults)
- Now that you have indexes, they must be updated when you are inserting - if everything fits in RAM this should be OK, see first point
- You should also check your Disk IO to see how that is performing - how does your background flush average look?
- Are you running the correct filesystem (XFS, ext4) and a kernel version later than 2.6.25? (earlier versions have issues with fallocate())

Some good general information for follow up can be found here:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Production+Notes